# Encode data into 1 byte

Tags: binary, byte, encode

I have to encode data to 1 byte. I have the following data as of now.

size - 500 ml and 1 litre

Frequency - 0 to 12

% - 0-100

So i decided to break the data into the following -

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

1st bit - Size - 0 for 500ml and 1 for 1 litre

2-5 bits - Frequency - 0 to 12 (0000 for 0 and 1100 for 12)

I am not sure how to get the % in this setting. Am i looking into solving this in a wrong way? Is there any other way to do it. Any direction is highly appreciated.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean with `get the %`.. Can you clarify?

Comment: the percentage is a value ranging from 0 to 100

Comment: I was puzzled at first too, but he just want to store three quantitties: Size (500 / 1000), Frequency (0 to 12) and Percentage (0 to 100).

But unfortunately, I don't think it is possible to store it in one byte... you would need 7 bits to store the percentage, but you are only left with 3 :(

Comment: Unless there is some sort of relation between these numbers such that one could be inferred from another, I don't know if this is possible

Comment: So i guess it can be done using 2 bytes

Comment: @Dan a minimum of 12 bits would be needed so you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are left with 3 bits. you need to store a value between 0-100, which atleast needs 7 bits. (2^7 = 128). However, if you only need 8 different percentage values, you can get away with using 3 bits